# Hide inner div(s) that exceed outer div height

Tags: jquery, css

[image: Illustration]

The entire element should be hidden. There should be no scrollbars on the outer div. Can this be achieved with CSS only or is jQuery needed? How can this be implemented?

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: You can try "overflow: hidden", but I think that will only hide the part of the div that is greater than the height (and not the whole div).

Comment: Do you want to hide the complete element? or still show the part that is within the outer div bounds?

Comment: Yes, I want to hide the complete element.

Comment: You will need to use Javascript. jQuery will make it easier.

Comment: Do you want to still be able to get to the hidden elements? If so maybe just use overflow:auto on the outer div. This will create a scroll bar allowing users to get to the hidden elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general idea is the following:

```
$("div div").filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        pTop = $this.parent().offset().top,    // parent position
                                               // (no need if parent has
                                               //  "position: relative")

        pHeight = $this.parent().height(),     // parent inner height

        eTop = $this.offset().top,             // block position
                                               // (can be replaced with
                                               //  "$this.position().top"
                                               //  if parent has
                                               //  "position: relative")

        eHeight = $this.outerHeight(true);     // block outer height

    return (eTop + eHeight) > (pTop + pHeight);
}).hide();
```

(Theoretically this *should* work.)

---

Another approach:

```
var sumHeight = 0;
$("div div").filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        pHeight = $this.parent().height();      // parent inner height

    sumHeight += $this.outerHeight(true);       // + block outer height

    return sumHeight > pHeight;
}).hide();
```

Comment: Suppose the outer div is name "mainLeft" and inner divs are named "row", should it then be $("mainLeft row")?

Comment: @user1750323 No, I do not select two `div`s. I just show that I select `div`s inside a `div`, i.e. blocks within a container. You can replace it with `$("#container .block")` or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't tested at all, and will very likely need to be tweaked, but to give you a general idea of how you could do it with jQuery:

```
var container = $('#container');
var element = $('#element');

if ((element.position().top + element.position.height()) > container.height()) {
    element.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `overflow:hidden;` property to the outer div.

Comment: this will cut the lowest div hiding it just partially